# onedrive for business authentication client credentials flow oAuth 2.0

Tags: java, azure, oauth-2.0, authorization, onedrive

I'm working on onderive for business and require client credential flow for accessing it through java. can anyone provide me authentication example for the above mentioned source so that i can work on it!

I'm trying to follow this flow, but i was missing some context which left me with partial work.

I successfully created certificate and uploaded to manifest. But couldn't get any further. could you please help me on the process of how to authenticate based on this X.509 certificate.

Comment: I have successfully attained an access token using client credentials flow, but its app only token. I have followed this [doc](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/#comment-5803) and was successful in getting app only access token. As mentioned by the author (Matthias Leibmann) app only support has been added to one drive for business. But i have lost the way. i have been trying for all the resources but failed.

Comment: And for the resource (https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0) response doesnt even gives an access token. Am i missing any permission that need to be given to access one drive or is that the reousrce using for one drive for business is wrong. Any one help me out!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to [Use a SAML 2.0 identity provider to implement single sign-on](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn641269.aspx).

But I think that using OAuth2 for authentication is the recommended way.

There is a [sample project](https://github.com/wooti/onedrive-java-client) for OneDrive in Java on GitHub that I think you can refer to and use the url of OneDrive for Business instead of the url for OneDrive.

For example, to get an authorization code, using the url for OneDrive for Business `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}` instead of the url for OneDrive `https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id={client_id}&scope={scope}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}`.

In the sample project, the [`OneDriveAuthorisationProvider.java`](https://github.com/wooti/onedrive-java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/wouterbreukink/onedrive/client/authoriser/OneDriveAuthorisationProvider.java) implemented the authentication process that you can change the code to be compatible with OneDrive for Business.

As references, please see the docments below.

1. OneDrive authentication and sign-in https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm
2. OneDrive for Business authentication and sign in https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi @peterPan, thanks for this resolution. I have a found a way for authenticating through oAuth 2.0. There  is a [doc specified by microsoft for Graph api](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_authorization) in which we can authenticate a user with having a user consent. I found this usefull compared to client credentials flow.